# How to set rows with max value within group as true sql

Tags: sql, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

I have a table similar to this:

| ID | ORDER | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 |
| 99 | 41 | 17 |
| 12 | 34 | 24 |
| 99 | 42 | 12 |
| 12 | 33 | 15 |
| 12 | 33 | 38 |

I would like to look at the ID column, where if the ORDER value is the max value within the ID group, then to set it as TRUE, and the others as FALSE.

I tried to do

```
SELECT ID, ORDER,
CASE WHEN ORDER = MAX(ORDER) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS ACTIVE
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY ID, ORDER;
```

But that seems to just set every ACTIVE value to true.

Ultimately I am trying to end up with a table like

| ID | ORDER | AGE | ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | FALSE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | FALSE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | FALSE |

What would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing within the group ID, ORDER. But should not one of the ID=99 rows be ACTIVE?

Comment: @forpas Thanks for pointing that out, that was a typo, it's fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT ID, ORDER, AGE,
       ORDER = MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS ACTIVE
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to rank the rows using row_number.  Order by `order` and partition by `id`.  This will provide you with a rank value where you can set the `Active` flag `where rank = 1`.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html